# How to avoid obvious flash of the popup menu when navigating quickly?

Tags: vimrc

Vim's popup menu is a very cool and modern feature. However, if the list is very long (such as completion) and I keep pressing `<C-N>` to navigate through the menu quickly, the popup menu will flash to refresh the content, which is sometimes a little dizzy.
So what may be the cause? Is this a limit of the terminal or is there any plugin which make Vim inefficient?
Thanks very much!

Comment: See also https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/4036, which might be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an issue with Vim itself. When exploring the popup menu with Ctrl-N or Ctrl-P, Vim replaces your text with the highlighted item, which implies switching back-and-forth between the menu and the window behind it. You can bypass the issue by using the up and down arrows instead of Ctrl-P and Ctr-N, because in that case Vim does not perform text replacement (but then you'll need to press Enter to accept the highlighted item). Personally, I dislike the arrow keys so I use remappings to avoid them; for example:

```
inoremap <expr> n pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "n"
inoremap <expr> p pumvisible() ? "\<Up>" : "p"
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will check it later! I didin't notice this subtle difference before.

Comment: Keep me posted, as the flickering may have other causes too

Comment: Currently I do not have the condition to test it enough. Anyway, I map `<C-J>` and `<C-K>` to navigate the popup menu. `inoremap <expr> <C-J> pumvisible() ? "<Down>" : "<C-J>"` and `inoremap <expr> <C-K> pumvisible() ? "<Up>" : "<C-K>"`.

Comment: By the way, what does \ in "\<Down>" mean?

Comment: Sorry about the backslash, it means nothing and I put it out of habit (it is needed in string constants), but the mapping should work without it, as your own example shows.

Answer (score 1):

> So what may be the cause? Is this a limit of the terminal or is there
>   any plugin which make Vim inefficient?

In order to understand if it is a terminal limitation you could try to reproduce the problem in different terminals and using gVim.

If you are suspicious that it could be a plugin that may be causing the problem then you could follow the procedure described on [Vim-FAQ  2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5). Some relevant parts follows:

> 2.5. I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a
>        problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?
>
> First, you need to find out, whether the error is in the actual
>   runtime files or any plugin that is distributed with Vim or whether it
>   is a simple side effect of any configuration option from your .vimrc
>   or .gvimrc. So first, start vim like this:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> this starts Vim in nocompatible mode (-N), without reading your
>   viminfo file (-i NONE), without reading any configuration file (-u
>   NONE for not reading .vimrc file and -U NONE for not reading a .gvimrc
>   file) or even plugin.
>
> If the error does not occur when starting Vim this way, then the
>   problem is either related to some plugin of yours or some setting in
>   one of your local setup files. You need to find out, what triggers the
>   error, you try starting Vim this way:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N
> ```
>
> If the error occurs, the problem is your .viminfo file. Simply delete
>   the viminfo file then. If the error does not occur, try:
>
> ```
> vim -u ~/.vimrc --noplugin -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> This will simply use your .vimrc as configuration file, but not load
>   any plugins. If the error occurs this time, the error is possibly
>   caused by some configuration option inside your .vimrc file. Depending
>   on the length of your vimrc file, it can be quite hard to trace the
>   origin within that file.
>
> The best way is to add :finish command in the middle of your .vimrc.
>   Then restart again using the same command line. If the error still
>   occurs, the bug must be caused because of a setting in the first half
>   of your .vimrc. If it doesn't happen, the problematic setting must be
>   in the second half of your .vimrc. So move the :finish command to the
>   middle of that half, of which you know that triggers the error and
>   move your way along, until you find the problematic option. If your
>   .vimrc is 350 lines long, you need at a maximum 9 tries to find the
>   offending line (in practise, this can often be further reduced, since
>   often lines depend on each other).
>
> If the problem does not occur, when only loading your .vimrc file, the
>   error must be caused by a plugin or another runtime file (indent
>   autoload or syntax script). Check the output of the :scriptnames
>   command to see what files have been loaded and for each one try to
>   disable each one by one and see which one triggers the bug. Often
>   files that are loaded by vim, have a simple configuration variable to
>   disable them, but you need to check inside each file separately.